# javascript code written in separate to the html markup

Tags: javascript

what's wrong with this code, i have  included the file but when i run  it doesn't give  the result  i intended(customized design of video player),any one who is aware about javascript can help.......

```
function dofirst() {

    //get values of buttons
    var movie = document.getElementById("movie");
    var playOrpause = document.getElementById("playOrpause");
    var mute = document.getElementById("mute");
    var fullscreen = document.getElementById("fullscreen");

    //get values of sliders
    var seekbar = document.getElementById("seekbar");
    var myvolume = document.getElementById("volume");


    //add the event listeners to buttons

    playOrpause.addEventListener('click', playme, false);
    mute.addEventListener('click', mute_me, false);
    fullscreen.addEventListener('click', scree_full, false);

    //add the event listener to sliders 
    seekbar.addEventListener('change', change_me, false);
    seekbar.addEventListener('timeupdate', update_me, false);
    seekbar.addEventListener('mousedown', mous_down, false);
    seekbar.addEventListener('mouseup', mous_up, false);
    myvolume.addEventListener('change', volume_up, false);

}

//the functions of play button



function playme() {
    if (movie.paused == true) {
        movie.play();
        //update button status
        playOrpause.innerHTML = 'pause';
        else {
            movie.pause();
            //update button status
            playOrpause.innerHTML = 'play';
        }
    }
}

//the functions of mute button



function mute_me() {
    if (movie.muted == false) {
        movie.muted = true;
        //update button status
        mute.innerHTML = 'unmute';
    } else {
        movie.muted = false;
        //update button status
        mute.innerHTML = 'mute';
    }



}

//the functions of fullscreen button


function scree_full() {
    if (movie.requestFullscreen) {
        movie.requestFullscreen();
    }
    //for mozilla  firefox browser
    else if (movie.mozRequestFullscreen) {

        movie.mozRequestFullscreen();
    }
    //for google chrome browsers
    else if (movie.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        movie.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
}

//the functions for seekbar 

function change_me() {
    //calculate current time of the video
    var time = movie.duration * (seekbar.value / 100);
    //update the current time of the video
    movie.currentTime = time;
}

//update the seekbar when the video plays

function update_me() {
    var size = movie.currentTime * (100 / movie.duration);

    //update the size of the seekbar
    seekbar.value = size;

}

//pause the video when the seekbar is dragged


function mous_down() {
    movie.pause();
}

//play the video when the seekbar is dropped

function mous_up() {
    movie.play();
}

//the function for the volume bar

function volume_up() {
    movie.volume = myvolume.value;
}
window.addEventListener("load", dofirst, false);
```

Comment: at what stage did the error appear?

Comment: ___In the code formatting stage.___

Comment: And when I try to format the code, "The post is mainly code!"!

Comment: check if..else brackets - playme() function

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there are no syntax errors in your code....For instance, you seem to be using 'mous_up()' instead of 'mouse_up()'. From my own experience, javascript code doesn't run when there are any syntax errors.

Comment: "mous_up()" is just a function name

Comment: My mistake,I realized that later while revisiting your code. All the same, javascript only fails to run due to syntax errors...please check thoroughly for any